# In-class default values initialization order

Tags: c++, constructor, c++11, initialization

When do class members get their default values in c++11? Is the following code legitimate?

```
class C {
    void* buffer;
    uint16_t& crc = *reinterpret_cast <uint16_t*> (buffer);
public:
    explicit C (void* p) : buffer (p) {}
};
```

I expect, that the default value of crc is just syntax sugar, so that crc is initialized after buffer has been. Am I correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order of initialization of non-static data members is specified in paragraph 10 of 12.6.2 Initializing bases and members [class.base.init]
(emphasis mine):

> In a non-delegating constructor, initialization proceeds in the following order:
>
> [... things regarding bases]
>
> **— Then, non-static data members are initialized in the order they were declared in the class definition
>   (again regardless of the order of the mem-initializers).**
>
> — Finally, the compound-statement of the constructor body is executed.

As you can see, whether the members are initialized with a so called *mem-initializer* (i.e. inside a constructor, before its body) or a *brace-or-equal-initializer* (i.e. in the class definition) or with nothing at all has no bearing on initialization order.

Comment: Thank you. I was just looking through the standard draft, missed that.

Answer (score 1):

The order is specified in C++11 §12.6.2[class.base.init]/10. It depends only on the order you declare the data members. Since `buffer` appears before `crc` it is fine.

> Then, non-static data members are initialized in the order they were declared in the class definition (again regardless of the order of the *mem-initializers*).